# Unity2D - Level with invisible collisions

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision-detection, unity3d-2dtools

In my Unity2D project I want that to load a level as a sprite from my resources. The game is a top down view. I then want to add invisible collision boxes where the walls in the level-image are.
How would I do that?
I have attached a box collider to my player and now? Creating an empty game object with another box collider doesnt work.

Comment: You should make your level complete in your scene first. Add the sprite, place several box colliders in the positions needed, ensuring those gameobjects are children of your level GameObject. Then create a prefab out of it and instantiate the level prefab whenever you need it.

Comment: @Savlon that was not my question. My problem is that the level colliders dont block the players box collider. Sorry if i was unclear about that.

Comment: Oh I see... Are you using 2D colliders for all objects? And does your player have a rigidbody2D attached?

Comment: @Savlon Jup, all 2D colliders. I do have a rigidbody for my player, but im not sure about the settings. Do i have to pay attention to something in particular?

Comment: Don't have it set as kinematic.

Comment: @Savlon I dont but it still doesnt work. The player sort of slides off the box collider.

Comment: Is it colliding though? Have you set your gravity scale to 0 seems as though it's a top down view? (Presuming you're using the x and y axis' only)

Comment: @Savlon I tested it with Debug.Log() and OnTriggerEnter2D (). It doesnt even log the collision.

Comment: This is getting discussion is getting increasingly long and I don't think you understand triggers and collision in unity. I think it would be beneficial for you to read up on basic collision requirements. Hopefully it will guide you in the right direction. https://www.binpress.com/tutorial/unity-3d-collisions-basics/114

Comment: @Savlon Sorry if I am acting stupid, but I still dont get why the player can go into the wall. Do I need some scripting to achieve the wanted?

Comment: If you are using your colliders as triggers, then no physics collision will occur.

Comment: Uncheck the `Trigger` from colliders of wall and player

Answer (score 0):

See @Savlon comment, you need rigidbody with your collider component as well for empty objects. And they will provide blocking of player object if you player object also have collider and rigidbody. Don't mark your colliders as trigger and ensure they are on the same layers.